# Wordpress Elementor JavaScript bug

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I tried to add Javascript of current year in Elementors HTML code widget, and it worked. But now whenever I open Elementor editor of that page, only "2017" shows, the rest of the page is blank. How can I revert this or delete so it can be as in previous state?